# How to sort scores and assign positions based on the scores?

Tags: c++, mathematics, game-mechanics, leaderboards, sorting

I have three game objects each with an individual score. I was wondering how I should go about sorting these scores in ascending order. I want to also give these objects a position based on their score. Any help would be appreciated.

For example:

```
object1.score = 1300, 

object2.score = 3000,

object3.score = 2200
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
object1.position = 3,

object2.position = 1,

object3.position = 2
```

Game Object code:

```
SGameObject
{
    int cp = 0;
    int lap = 0;
    int score = 0;
    int position = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your objects into a `std::vector` (or even `std::array`) and then use `std::sort` with a custom comparator.
After that, if necessary, you can assign the indices in the list to the corresponding objects.

```
std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { 
    return a.score > b.score; });
```

Now `objects` contains the items sorted by their scores. To assign the positions, just loop over the objects again and assign their index to the position:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i)
    objects[i].position = i;  // Zero indexed, add one for one indexed.
```